# New xtext project couldn't find .settings/gradle.prefs

Tags: eclipse, gradle, xtext

Try to create new empty xtext project and get errors about missing gradle settings... what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: casn you file a ticket for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this happens if you use a older versin of gradle buildship. using the latest http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e45/releases/1.0/1.0.15.v20160425-1638 solves the problem for me

Comment: Thank you... It helped, but it's frustrating that I had the latest version of Eclipse, downloaded yesterday = (